# Magento Tax Calculation with Coupon Code

Tags: magento, coupon

If no coupon code is added the calculation of the tax and end price is fine. But if i add a coupon code (fixed price 10€ on basket total) the calculation of the tax is not correct and the basket total also. For better understanding what i meed i made screenshots.

Any Help is very appreciated!

[image: My Basket:]

[image: My Magento Tax Configuration:]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Describe how you want your tax to be calculated.

Answer (score 5):

Look under **System > Configuration > Tax**

Under **Calculation Settings**, you can set when the tax is applied; either `Before Discount` or `After Discount`

[image: Tax Calculation]